# Simple sqlite3 syntax question

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

Im new to sqlite3 (and databases in general for that matter). Anyway, in my database i have a date column and i wanted to get all of the data within the 3 days of the current date.  Here is the query I have.  I am just not sure if there is a built in way to get nearby dates in sqlite3.  I dont know what to put in the '?'s.

```
SELECT date FROM fooTable WHERE date('now') ???????
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (3 days is 3*86400 seconds):

```
SELECT date FROM fooTable WHERE strftime('%s', now) - strftime('%s',date) < 259200
```

Comment: You can do simple math. Did it work for you? I wasn't sure if you wanted relative time or day boundaries.

Comment: no it didnt work but im trying to play around with some other queries. i saved the dates in this format yyyy-mm-dd . i dont know if that has anything to do with it

Comment: What's your table definition?

Comment: foo(_id TEXT PRIMARY KEY, expirationDate TEXT, data Text);

Comment: `select * from foo WHERE strftime('%s','now') - strftime('%s',expirationDate) < 252900` should do what you want.